# Pandas - how to drop rows those are top n% in certain column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of two columns:

```
userID | count
A      | 15
B      | 12
```

about million of rows.
I would like to filter out userID with top n % of count values, as I suspect it is a bot activity.

I tried it with sorting by count, but I can only come up with the way to filter top n rows, not top n '%' rows.

what would be the pandas trick that I can use to filter out based on percentage?

Comment: Can you give a example with 10 rows and the matching expected output?

Comment: Can't you just sort by that column and delete the last n% of the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this input and that you want to drop the top 50% (0.5):

```
  userID  count
0      A     15
1      B     12
2      C      5
3      D     25
4      E     22
5      F      3
6      G      7
7      H      9
8      I     11
9      J      7
```

You can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by descending count, then compute the percent and its [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), finally use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter out the top values:

```
target = 0.5
(df.sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)
   .assign(pct=lambda d: d['count'].div(d['count'].sum()).cumsum())
   .loc[lambda d: d['pct'].gt(target).shift().bfill()]
)
```

Output:

```
  userID  count
1      B     12
8      I     11
7      H      9
6      G      7
9      J      7
2      C      5
5      F      3
```

Intermediate:

```
  userID  count       pct   keep
3      D     25  0.215517  False
4      E     22  0.405172  False
0      A     15  0.534483  False
1      B     12  0.637931   True
8      I     11  0.732759   True
7      H      9  0.810345   True
6      G      7  0.870690   True
9      J      7  0.931034   True
2      C      5  0.974138   True
5      F      3  1.000000   True
```